# Test if string is not equal to either of two strings

Tags: ruby, if-statement, logic

I am just learning RoR so please bear with me. I am trying to write an if or statement with strings.  Here is my code:

```
<% if controller_name != "sessions" or controller_name != "registrations" %>
```

I have tried many other ways, using parentheses and `||` but nothing seems to work. Maybe its because of my JS background...

How can I test if a variable is not equal to string one or string two?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a basic logic problem:

```
(a !=b) || (a != c)
```

will always be true as long as b != c. Once you remember that in boolean logic

```
(x || y) == !(!x && !y)
```

then you can find your way out of the darkness.

```
(a !=b) || (a != c) 
!(!(a!=b) && !(a!=c))   # Convert the || to && using the identity explained above
!(!!(a==b) && !!(a==c)) # Convert (x != y) to !(x == y)
!((a==b) && (a==c))     # Remove the double negations
```

The only way for (a==b) && (a==c) to be true is for b==c. So since you have given b != c, the `if` statement will always be false.

Just guessing, but probably you want

```
<% if controller_name != "sessions" and controller_name != "registrations" %>
```

Answer (score 15):

```
<% unless ['sessions', 'registrations'].include?(controller_name) %>
```

or

```
<% if ['sessions', 'registrations'].exclude?(controller_name) %>
```

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `exclude?' for ["", ""]:Array

Comment: Required something from ActiveSupport from Ruby on Rails


`require 'active_support/core_ext/enumerable'`