# ./geany_run_script.sh: Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf, getchar, geany

I want to create a simple program in C that will display a menu, and the user must choose from the choices by choosing a char. This is the code I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void menu();

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    menu();
    return 0;
}

void menu(){
    char choix;
    printf("(C)réer un fichier\n");
    printf("(L)ire un fichier\n");
    printf("(E)crire sur un fichier\n");
    printf("(S)upprimer un fichier\n");
    do{
        choix = tolower(getchar());
        printf(choix);
    }while((choix != 'c') || (choix != 'l') || (choix != 'e') || (choix != 's'));
    printf("end");
}
```

but when I run my application, I get this message in console:

```
./geany_run_script.sh: line 5:  6582 Segmentation fault (core dumped) "./main"
```

And this is a screenshot :

[image: screenshot of application]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The segmentation fault

[`printf`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/printf/)'s argument needs to be a string, but you're passing it a `char` in

```
printf(choix);
```

It's treating that character as a pointer, but it's not going to be a valid pointer, and it's pointing somewhere very low in memory that you should not be trying to access.  Instead, you should either pass `printf` a string with a format directive that expects a char, such as in

```
printf("%c", choix);
```

or you could use a function like [`putchar`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/putchar/) and do

```
putchar(choix);
```

### Looping condition problems

However, once you get that worked out, you'll have some problems ending your loop.  You end when

```
(choix != 'c') || (choix != 'l') || (choix != 'e') || (choix != 's')
```

but *every* character is *not* the same as at least one of `c`, `l`, `e`, or `s`.  That is, suppose the user types `x`.  Then the first part `(choix != 'c')` will be true and you'll quit.  The same thing would happen if the user had typed `e`, which is supposed to be one of your options.  If you're trying to loop until the user puts in one of the designated characters, you need to loop while

```
(choix != 'c') && (choix != 'l') && (choix != 'e') || (choix != 's')
```

That is, you continue looping as long as it's not `c`, *and* it's not `l`_, *and* it's not `e`, *and* it's not `s`.  You could also phrase this as "loop while it's not ( equal to `c` or `equal to`l` or …)", in which case you could loop while

```
!( choix == 'c' || choix == 'l' || choix == 'e' || choix == 's' )
```

This mistake actually appears somewhat frequently on Stack Overflow, but it's rather hard to search for.  Here's an answered question in Ruby that addresses this issue:

- [Test if string is not equal to either of two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16870540/1281433)

Comment: please see the modification I have made to my post

Comment: @user2874861 That's really a different problem, and you should ask it as a separate question, _especially_ after accepting the answer.  If this answer suitably answered the original question, you should leave it accepted, and ask your new question _as a new question_.

Comment: @user2874861 That said, I expect that what's happening is that you're trying a character, and then hitting Enter or Return, which is available on the next loop iteration.  Rather than just printing the character that they typed in, try something like `printf("The character %c is the character you typed.", choix)`, and I bet you'll see a new line in the middle of the output.

Answer (score 2):

[`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) expects a string (`char *`) as its first argument, you give it a `char` which it tries to interpret as a pointer. That points to some address it may not read causing a segmentation fault.

In the bottom of your screenshot you can see warnings from your compiler telling you this. Never ignore compiler warnings!

Print your character with [`putchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/putchar) or use `%c` in the `printf` format string:

```
printf("%c\n", choix);
```